# Restricting polynomials to lines

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Consider polynomial functions of degree at most $d$ on affine space $\mathbb{A}^n$.  They form a vector space $F_d$ of dimension $\binom{n+d}{d}$.

Consider lines $l_1, \dots , l_m$. Denote $G^{(i)}_d$ vector space polynomial function on line $l_i$. or each line we can consider restriction operator $r_i : F_d \rightarrow G^{(i)}_d $. Moreover we can consider 
$$G_d := \bigoplus_{i=1}^m G^{(i)}_d$$

$\dim G_d = m (d+1) $

Finally we introduse operator $R: F_d \rightarrow G_d $

$$R(f) = \big( r_1(f) , \dots , r_m (f) \big)$$

**Question** Does there exist set of lines such that $R$ is either injection of surjection?

**Examples** $m =1$. One line -- R is surjection.

$m=2$. Two lines. $R$ is surjection for $d>0$. For $d=0$ it is injection. For $d=1$ R is bijection.

$m=3$ $R$ is surjective for $d>1$. For $d = 0, 1$ operator $R$ is injective. In this case it is never bijection.

$m=4$. It is surjection for $d>2$. Otherwise injection. Never bijection.

$m=5$. Injection for $d<3$. Surjection for $d>3$. For d = 3 I do not know.

**Comment 1.** My question may seems weird: why am I asking about existence? But this condition is open. Then if there exist such set of lines then almost all sets of lines satisfies this condition.

**Comment 2** As consequence of first question: you may consider projective space instead of affine.

**Comment 3.** My original question was about cohomology of  twisted ideal sheaf of $l_1 \sqcup l_2 \sqcup \dots \sqcup l_m$. Also for my purpose I need only $n=3$.

Comment: Any finite collection of lines is Zariski closed of dimension one. There are always going to be non-zero regular functions that vanish on their union. However, for $n$ distinct lines, it must have degree at least $n$, so it may not be included in the vector space $F_d$.

Comment: I am to understand that $G_d^i$ is the quotient vector space $F_d/(f_i)$ where $(f_i)$ is the subspace generated by the linear equation $l_i$, yes? Anyway, I believe that the operator $R$ is surjective if and only if each pair of subspaces $(f_i), (f_j)$ is comaximal, i.e. $(f_i)+(f_j) = F_d$.

Comment: Polynomial of degree two  in three variables vanishes on infinitely many distinct lines. For every three lines there is a polynomial of degree two which vanishes on them.

Comment: I consider only non intersecting lines (actually this question is about generic lines, so this assumption is not restrictive at all). Of course $R$ is surjective for case of two lines (if degree is greater than 0). But what happens when you take more then two lines?